# Can I use the racing GPS in open-world play?

Tags: cyberpunk-2077

When you are doing street races for Claire, the racing route is mapped out using a gold arrows path on the ground.

However when driving in free play, the GPS is confined to dots on the minimap which causes me to miss pretty much every turn unless I drive just looking at the minimap.

Is there any way, through specific cars, cyberwear or progression to enable road based GPS instead of minimap GPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no open-world GPS system except for the minimap.